# How can i get the latitude and longitude values using zipcode in ios5?

Tags: ios, latitude-longitude, zipcode

I used   http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=csv&q=ZIPCODE
   this url to  get the latitude and longitude from zipcode..but im getting wrong latitude and longitude values.Is there any other services are available..

I locked here only...

Thanks in adv..

Comment: By  http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=csv&q=us-ZIPCODE using this link also it gives the correct latitude and longitude vallues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this API, its very useful:
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=tn-635113&sensor=false